# getElementsByName returns an element with a wrong name

Tags: javascript, dom

So in JS I cloned an element and changed all its children `name`s to get their index changed (e.g. `instanceActeurRole[0].siteId` becomes `instanceActeurRole[3].siteId`)

```
...
<table>
<tbody id="rolesdiv_xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="instanceActeurRole[0].siteId" value="920501">
</table>
...

var originalRolesDiv = document.getElementById("rolesdiv_xxxx");
var tableRoles = originalRolesDiv.parentNode;
var cloneRolesDiv = originalRolesDiv.cloneNode(true);
var inputElements = cloneRolesDiv.getElementsByTagName("input");
var nouveauIndex = 3;
for(var j = 0 ; j < inputElements.length ; j++){
    if(inputElements[j].name.indexOf('instanceActeurRole[0]') == 0) {
        inputElements[j].name = inputElements[j].name.replace("0",nouveauIndex);
    }
}
tableRoles.appendChild(cloneRolesDiv);
```

Now when I do

```
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId").length
2
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[1].name
"instanceActeurRole[3].siteId"
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[1].getAttribute('name')
"instanceActeurRole[3].siteId"
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId").length
2
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[0].name
"instanceActeurRole[0].siteId"
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[0].id
""
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[1].name
"instanceActeurRole[3].siteId"
>>document.getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")[1].id
""
```

I am working on IE8 in compatibility mode, so according to the docs [MSDN - getElementsByName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Gets a collection of objects based on the value of the **NAME** or **ID**
>   attribute.

**My question is :** Why did the `getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")` method return the element named `instanceActeurRole[3].siteId` ??

### ALTERNATIVELY (without the need to see any code)

in which situation would `getElementsByName(elemName)` return an element which has a different name than the one passed to the method ?

Comment: Could you set up a working example on jsfiddle of this ?

Comment: Or here. StackSnippets FTW.

Comment: I think it would be very helpful if we had the HTML also

Comment: Can you please provide some HTML and the browser, the version and the operating system you are seeing this behaviour?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry in my original post (that i never posted) it was said IE8 Compatibilty mode. And i'm working on the fiddle.

Comment: I'm downvoting this due to the lack of HTML.

Comment: I added the HTML, GIVE ME BACK MY VOTE haha :)

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this with HTML where that name occurs natively, instead using JS to clone and rename elements?

Comment: I would have loved to be able to do this but it only occurs on a large page generated by the server, and it will take some time to simplify and post a code snippet. Anyways, my question is more about the method itself. in which situation would getElementsByName(elemName) return an element which has a different name than the one passed to the method ?

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
if(inputElements[j].name.indexOf('instanceActeurRole[0]') == 0) {
    inputElements[j].name = inputElements[j].name.replace("0",nouveauIndex);
}
```

with

```
var name = inputElements[j].getAttribute('name');
if (name.indexOf('instanceActeurRole[0]') == 0) {
    inputElements[j].setAttribute('name', name.replace("0", nouveauIndex));
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) that's an answer to a followup question I made on @Guffa's answer. My question is : "Why" did the getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId") method return the element named instanceActeurRole[3].siteId ?

Answer (score -1):

**YOUR QUESTION** Why did the getElementsByName method return the element name instanceActeurRole[3].siteId

**omg, you did:**

```
var nouveauIndex = 3;
```

and then set name to

```
'instanceActeurRole[0].siteId'.replace('0', nouveauIndex)
```

what did u expect it to be?! ?! ?! other than instanceActeurRole[3].siteId ?! ?! ?!

Comment: Why did the `getElementsByName("instanceActeurRole[0].siteId")` method return the element named `instanceActeurRole[3].siteId` ? :)